# Thare is padding (space) in menu HTML

Tags: html, css, menu

Merhaba,

i have padding space in menu html. Codes are below. I cannot find the reason. Please look the code.

[The menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHhOA.png)

Code :

```
<style type="text/css">
    *{

      margin: 0;
      outline: 0;
      list-style: none;
      text-decoration: none;

    }

    .menu{

      width: 1350px;
      height: 30px;
      float: left;
      background: #996600;
      position: relative;
      top: 185px;

    }

    .menu a {

      width: auto;
      height: 30px;
      float: left;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: white;
      padding-left: 18px;
      padding-right: 18px;
      border-right: solid 1px white;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-decoration: none;

    }

    .menu li{

      width: auto;
      height: 46px;
      float: left;
      position: relative;

    }

    .menu ul li ul{

      width: 180px;
      height: auto;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      background: #996600;
      top: 30px;
      left: 1px;
      z-index: 1px;
      display: none;

    }

    .menu ul li ul a{

      width: 140px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      float: left;
      padding: 0 0 0 17px;
      border-top: dashed 1px gray;
      background: none;

    }

    .menu ul li ul li{

      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;

    }

    .menu li:hover > ul{

      display: block;

    }

    .menu a:hover{

      color: white;
      background: black;

    }

    .menu ul li ul li ul{

      width: 180px;
      height: auto;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      background: #6c6b6b;
      top: 0px;
      left: 180px;
      z-index: 1;
      display: none;

    }

  </style>
```

Html :

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="blabla.php">Anasayfa</a></li>
    <?php

    $vericek61 = $baglanti1 -> prepare("select * from menu order by no asc");
    $vericek61->execute();

    while ($bilgiler61 = $vericek61 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

      $menuid = $bilgiler61['no'];

      $vericek64 = $baglanti1 -> prepare("select * from altmenu where anamenuid = ? order by no asc");
      $vericek64 -> bindParam(1, $menuid);
      $vericek64 -> execute();
      $vericek64say = $vericek64 -> rowCount();

      if ($vericek64say == 0) {

        ?>

        <li><a href="blabla.php?menu=<?php echo($bilgiler61['menuadi']); ?>"><?php echo($bilgiler61['menuadi']); ?></a></li>

        <?php

      }else{

        ?>

        <li><a href="egoldshop.php?menu=<?php echo($bilgiler61['menuadi']); ?>"><?php echo($bilgiler61['menuadi']); ?></a>
        <ul>
          <?php

          $vericek63 = $baglanti1 -> prepare("select * from altmenu where anamenuid = ? order by no asc");
          $vericek63 -> bindParam(1, $menuid);
          $vericek63 -> execute();

          while ($bilgiler63 = $vericek63 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            ?>

            <li><a href="blabla.php?altmenu=<?php echo($bilgiler63['menuadi']); ?>"><?php echo($bilgiler63['menuadi']); ?></a></li>

            <?php

          }

          ?>
        </ul></li>

        <?php

      }

    }

    ?>

  </ul>
  </div>
```

How can i delete this space padding ?

I need your help help me please.

Note : I have a French, but i don't have a good English. We can speak French.

Please do not make fun of my English.

Comment: Where is the HTML?

Comment: Sorry its not there

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox or Chrome developer tools / inspect, this will show you the element and the applied styles. In the applied styles you can check which rules superseed other rules, this way you can find what style is the culprit of the padding.

Also, you should use a css reset (search internet for it). The idea is every browser has it's own defaults, so you reset the styles and then apply the styles you want/need.

Comment: it's not an error, first of all, this is "z-index", nothing to do with padding. Also, it's not an error, it's showing you that this property it's not applied, because another style superseeds this. This is Cascading Style Sheets, the styles applies according to a cascade. You should check how CSS works. check this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/jUPdL)
in the image you can see there are 3 styles, for different elements, the one at the top is the style used. The others were overwritten for other styles.

Comment: do i need to delete it?

Comment: i don't understand.